# Unable to res.send in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I am having issue sending response with express.

I have read in other questions that maybe changing the err, res to other variables may fix this issue however it doesn't.

```
router.post('/checkPaid', (req, res, next) => {
  db.query(`SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address = ?`, req.body.email_address, (err, res) => {
    if(err)
    {
      throw err
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('User found')
      db.query(`SELECT course_paid FROM users WHERE email_address = ?`, req.body.email_address, (error, results) => {
        if(error)
        {
          console.log(error)
        }
        else
        {
          results.send('test')
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```
 throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: results.send is not a function
```

Comment: `results.send` that you are trying to use isn't coming from Express but from your `db.query`.

Comment: Another problem is that you are shadowing `res`.

Comment: hmm, I'm a little confused on how to do multiple requests to the database in one post request then. Everything I find online is very mixed with people writing it in different layouts. Some people use promises some are using try or catch. I'm not sure which I should use. Also do not understand what you mean by shadowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using res.send('test') instead of results.send('test'), because res is express response object.

EDIT:

```
router.post('/checkPaid', (req, res, next) => {
  db.query(`SELECT email_address FROM users WHERE email_address = ?`, req.body.email_address, (err, results) => {
    if(err)
    {
      throw err
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('User found')
        db.query(`SELECT course_paid FROM users WHERE email_address = ?`, req.body.email_address, (error, results) => {
            if(error)
            {
                console.log(error)
            }
            else
            {
                res.send('test')
            }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Still get the same error. res.send is not a function

Comment: In the first db call change res by results or any other variable name. Because the res overlaps the express res. You have a name conflicts

Comment: How would I go around to fix this? I've tried changing varible names but can't seem to fix the error.

Comment: Check out the edit I made to my original answer

Comment: It works! I see where I went wrong now thanks for the help sir. Would you write your code like this or do you think there is a better way to do this kind of request?

Comment: You're welcome my friend. Instead of making two queries to the database you can make group them to just one query